# bash: search for string, copy string next to it and list all for further post-processing

Tags: arrays, string, bash, list, file

I have the following challenge:

my *source_file.txt* contains:

```
track001="alpha"

some text ... but also again the string track001 without " symbol... some more text 

track002="beta"

some text ... but also again the string track002 without " symbol ... some more text       

track027="gamma"

some text ... but also again the string track003 without " symbol ... some more text 

track...="..."

... about 30 entries.
```

Now, I want to

1. search for the string next to **trackxxx="** (=> find the alpha, beta and gamma string)
2. afterwards provide the list to the user for further pre-processing in the terminal:

```
| Reference | Title  | Status            |
|---------- |--------| ------------------|
| 001       | alpha  | [ not selected ]  |
| 002       | beta   | [ not selected ]  |
| ...       | ...    | [ not selected ]  |
| 027       | gamma  | [ not selected ]  |

type Reference number (xxx): < user prompt>
change Status (selected = 1 / not selected = 0): < user prompt >
```

I thought about:

1. to copy the file and delete all lines which do not start with **trackxxx="** but I guess there is nice *sed* which does the magic.
2. I need to paste all into a matrix to ease the pre-processing
3. for the pre-processing I would like to keep it simple (terminal interaction) no zenity etc.. Maybe someone has an idea to make the selector operation more user friendly.

Appreciate your support, thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but `sed -n 's/^track\(.*\)="\([^"]*\).*/ \1 \2  /p'` will provide you numbers and titles, which you can then pipe into a `while read number title ; do`-loop

Comment: Could you please explain the parts of `'s/^track\(.*\)="\([^"]*\).*/ \1 \2  /p'`?

Answer (score 0):

As a partial answer, because of the request for explanation of my comments:
`sed -n 's/^track\(.*\)="\([^"]*\).*/ \1 \2  /p'` will give you a list of

```
001 alpha
002 beta
...
027 gamma
```

which can be fed into a for-loop in bash to do the actual processing.

- `sed -n` will not produce output, unless a line is explicitly printed
- `s/`*pattern*`/`*replacement*`/` replaces the *pattern* by the *replacement*
- `^track` matches `track` if it is at the beginning of a line (`^`)
- `\(.*\)` creates a capture group; the `\(` opens the capture group and the `\)` closes it. The capture group contains all characters up to the next element in the pattern
  -`="` This is the next element in the pattern: literal `="`
- `\([^"]*\)` second capture group. All character that are not `"` are added to this group.
- `.*` the rest of the line. Will most probably begin with a `"`, but if you forget the closing `"`, that's ok too.
  -The replacement string `\1 \2` is a combination of the two capture group, `\1` for the first and `\2` for the second.
- `p` Explicitly print this line if the pattern is matched. Because of the `-n`, normal output is suppressed, and you will get only the explicitly printed lines.